# HTML Tidy for VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there an equivalent way of achieving what [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) does to HTML code for VBA code? I just inherited a rats nest of Excel VBA, and I was hoping to just make it easier to read before diving in. I don't mind if I have to export it first; I'm already using [VBA Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) to make the thing work well with Git. Any suggestions?

Comment: I find the best way to clean up VBA is to delete the spreadsheet ;-)

Comment: @JonEgerton - Heh, we call that the "backup plan". At this point, I'm not sure which would take more time... figuring out this buggy mess or writing my own buggy mess.

Comment: MZ-Tools and SmartIndenter might help, but probably not a lot ( http://www.hitechcoach.com/index.php?option=com_weblinks&view=category&id=56%3Aaccess-developer-tools-add-ins-and-vba-code&Itemid=23 )

Comment: +1 @Remou for Smart Indenter, makes things much neater. You could also tokenize each VB module into an array to do things like remove empty lines.

Comment: @Remou - Does that work with Office 2007? The site only lists up to '03.

Comment: +1 @Remou - Smart Indenter and MZ-Tools are two excellent tools that you should have if you need to work with legacy VB6/VBA. Smart Indenter will format/tidy the code with quite flexible options. MZ-Tools can highlight unused variables/functions, show you everywhere a procedure is called and loads of other things, just the sort of things you need when trying to untangle the spaghetti.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a utility that will (try) to clean up code: [Smart Indenter v3.5](http://oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm)

After testing, I can confirm it works in Office 2007 and Office 2010 - it appears in the context menu when you right click on code

Comment: Do you know if that will work with Office 2007? It's not listed as being supported.

Comment: yes, it works - it appears in the context menu when you right click on code